# How can I add language support to Vuetify 3.3.4 date picker?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, date, datepicker, vuetify.js

I tried to add language support to vuetify date picker component. In default language (en) there is no problem but when i change the locale for example  Turkish ("tr") i get an error like : **Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getTime')**.

Here is the error that i get.

[image: Cannot read properties of undefined)]

plugins/vuetif.js

```
import '@mdi/font/css/materialdesignicons.css'
import 'vuetify/styles'
import * as labs from "vuetify/labs/components";
// Translations provided by Vuetify
import { en, tr } from "vuetify/locale";

// Composables
import { createVuetify } from 'vuetify'

// https://vuetifyjs.com/en/introduction/why-vuetify/#feature-guides
export default createVuetify({
  components: {
    ...labs,
  },
  locale: {
    locale: "tr",
    fallback: "en",
    messages: { tr, en },
  },
  theme: {
    themes: {
      light: {
        colors: {
          primary: '#1867C0',
          secondary: '#5CBBF6',
        },
      },
    },
  },
})
```

App.vue

```
<template>
  <v-container>
    <v-row>
      <v-col cols="6">
        <date-input></date-input>
        <date-input></date-input>
      </v-col>  
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
  
</template>

<script>
import DateInput from './components/DateInput.vue';

export default {
  components: {
    DateInput,
  },
}
</script>
```

Here is the codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/p/github/eguvenc/test/main

How can i fix it ?